# How call js function in html and then execute servlet?

Tags: javascript, html, servlets

I have html:

```html
<body>
<div class="cover">
    <form name="registform" action="doRegist" method="post" >
        <input type="submit" value="regist" onclick="formValidation()">
    </form>
</div>

<script src="resources/js/validation.js"></script>
</body>
```

I want js function "formValidation" to be performed first and then servlet "doRegist", but my programm ignore js function. Please, help

Update
js:

```js
function formValidation() {
 var login = document.registform.userName;
 if(validateLogin(login)) {
 
 }
 return false;
}
function validateLogin(login) {
 var loginformat =  /^[a-z]+([_]?[a-z0-9]+)$/i;
 var loginlen = login.value.length;
 if(loginlen < 5) {
  alert("You have entered an invalid login!");
  document.registform.userid.focus();
  return false;
 }
 if(login.value.match(loginformat)) {
  document.registform.userid.focus();
  return true;
 } else {
  alert("You have entered an invalid login!");
  document.registform.userid.focus();
  return false;
 }
}
```

Comment: what is your formValidation do?

Comment: When I run my file separately, not on the server, then js function works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have an action defined in your form, the browser will submit the form. If you need to cancel that, you need to call `preventDefault()` on event passed to `formValidation`. To do this you call the function like this `onclick="formValidation(event)"` and inside you function do this:

`function formValidation(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  ...
}`

This way you can cancel the event, and you form will not be submited. 
If you later decide to submit it (in case validation passes), you have to do it manually with something like `document.registform.submit()`.

N.B. Keep in mind that you are only initing the validation process at button click, while your form can be submitted differently, like return key pressed in one of text inputs. I recommend using `onsubmit` method instead.